# Symfony2 error when installing via composer

Tags: php, symfony, installation, composer-php

I am trying to install Symfony2 via composer on an Ubuntu server:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /var/www/dev/myproject 2.1.7
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
- Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%
    rm: cannot remove `/var/www/dev/myproject/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle': Directory not empty



  [ErrorException]
  ZipArchive::extractTo(): File name too long
```

Google didn't help, any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your user has permission to remove that folder?

Comment: Yes, also tried it as root, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem had to do with the linux server being a VM and the folder I tried to install symfony2 in was a folder shared from windows (the host) ...

After rebooting that error went away (leaving me with lots of random composer errors, but those are not in the scope of this question ;))

Comment: Yup, I've had that. What I do is setup the install into /var/www/xxx/ and then have a script that when the machine boots copies the files from /vagrant over to the /var/www/xxx/ folder.

Obviously replace /vagrant with your share if you're not using vagrant. If you use an IDE like PHP Storm, you then need to setup a share of the /var/www/xxx folder in order to push the local changes to the files into the /var/www/xxx folder. Its a bit of a long way round, but it removes any issues (mostly speed) from using the windows share directly. (And you WILL NOT want to run symfony over a share.)

Answer (score 0):

try by going inside the directory where you want to install it and then execute

`php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject 2.1.7`

Comment: I tried that (and every other combination I could think of), but it didn't help ...

Comment: @MarkGibson first try removing everythng from vendor directory by `sudo rm -rf vendor/*` then try